# getAssets is not working in Android Studio but it is working in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I am trying to move my SVN project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I am able to build the project using Maven in Android Studio.

But getAssets() is not working in Android Studio. It is working fine in Eclipse. I am trying to open config file which is present in assets folder and getting `FileNotFoundException`. If I am trying to run `getContext().getAssets()` any where in code App is crashing.

Any idea why it is working in Eclipse and not in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Make sure  that file in asset folder

Comment: where is the assests  folder?

Comment: Probably what you think is the assets folder in your project is not what the Android Gradle plugin thinks is the assets folder.

Comment: @sasikumar config file is present in asset folder.

Comment: @laalto I am using Maven to build project.

Comment: @Raghunandan , Assests folder is inside my project's home directory.

Comment: put your assests folder like yourdirectory\app\src\main\assests\config.
hope it work..

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistaken assets folder in android-studio,it's different from exlipse,your project structor maybe like this:

[image: http://envyandroid.com/content/images/2014/02/project-structure.png]
<sub>(source: [envyandroid.com](http://envyandroid.com/content/images/2014/02/project-structure.png))</sub>